# How do I access a parameterized method inside a controller from a nuget package?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a nuget package which contains an MVC controller - MyController which has a method `MethodWithStringParameter(string a)` and another method `MethodWithoutParameters()`.
I have installed this nuget package in my MVC service and have registered the controller and the routes.

```
public sealed class MyController : Controller
{
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage MethodWithStringParameter(string a)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
        };
    }

    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage MethodWithoutParameters()  
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
        };
    }
}
```

When I try hitting `MethodWithStringParameter` method, I get an exception

> Invalid JSON primitive: a.

However, I am able to hit the method `MethodWithoutParameters` without any issues.

Detailed exception

> Type: "System.ArgumentException"
>
> Message: "Invalid JSON primitive: a."
>
> StackTrace: " at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject() at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth) at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit) at System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)"

Comment: I also tried using some of the solutions provided here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846158/knockout-and-mvc3-posting-json-to-action-serializing-twice-cant-convert-to-c but that did not help.

Comment: What request are you sending?

Comment: Sending both as post requests using Chrome's Advanced Rest Client app.

Passing a="1" as raw body for the first method and nothing for the second. (Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8) for both

Comment: That isn't valid JSON.  What do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried posting empty body to this url `http://domainname/My/MethodWithStringParameter?a=abcd`